# block chain? What are the solutions for?

Tags: bcrypt

What are the mathematic equations used for cruptocurrency block chain?

No one has been able to answer the question.

As what is the whole picture if their is one and who gives up the coin for the reward?

Answer (score 1):

To be simple, you need to solve 'Next Block X' in a problem like this:

```
HashFunction(BlockContent + Next Block X) 
    < HashFunction(CurrentBlockContent + Current Block X)
```

Since it's a hash function then there is no way to do it, currently, without trying every possible value of X.

When a node begin to solve the problem, it includes the reward to it in the block content first, then solve the problem, if X is valid, and the reward is a reasonable number (transaction fee + block reward) then other nodes will accept that block, means that node got the reward. (no body gives the reward).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm trying to see what the problem to be solved is for? Is it part of an AI solution or cure for cancer? No one has been able to zone in and answer exactly what the equations are for or their origin although I know they are from anonymous entities. Hence the reward part is way to lure the The Who and What for.

Comment: No, the problem is made difficult so that only 1 can solve in an amount of time to avoid double spending. It doesn't cure cancer or even get you to bed on time...

Comment: That makes more sense but still not an answer of what the actually problem is for...

Comment: Is for avoiding double spending... Because solving the problem takes time, in 10 minutes, only 1 node can solve the problem and broadcast the result to other nodes to continue solving the next problem and the transactions included in that solution are valid. Imagine that attacker spend the same coin on 2 transactions T1 and T2. Node N1 included first transaction in the block and solve the problem and broadcast the solution across network. Hence T1 is valid and T2 is dropped. There is very small possibility that another node include T2 and solve the problem at the same time as N1.

Comment: Yes I'm very clear on the process but what is the solution(s) for? Are these equations for NASA? Are they for A logarithm that's part of a chain to solve the molecular answer to get to the fifth dimension? I just can't seem to find anyone to answer the specific question what are the equations ultimately for.? Make sense?

Comment: No.. the problem is not for solving any real life issue. it's just like lottery. the winning number is no use

Comment: That makes sense . But still with so much computing power behind it all just to solve it seems too good to be true. I guess its my turn to join the party and start mining ⛏⛏